# Where is the strong name key password stored?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I don't usually bother with signing my .NET assemblies, so I don't know much beyond the basic mechanics of it. For a small project I'm working on, it was necessary to sign, and I created a new key, protected with a password.

I expected to be prompted for this password at some point in time when recompiling the assembly, but I've never needed to enter it anywhere after creating the key file. This seems to defeat the purpose of password protecting the key in the first place.

I imagine the password is cached somewhere, but where? Is it in some kind of private storage? If I give someone else my entire solution directory with the key file in it, will they be prompted for the password I entered, or will they be able to sign the assembly without the password?

There are lots of articles on the internet about strong name keys and using them, but for some odd reason they all gloss over how the password is actually used by Visual Studio.

**Update:**
Restarting Visual Studio (and Windows) has no effect, so the caching appears to be persistent. Deleting the .suo file does not change the fact that no password is needed to sign the assembly.

Comment: How did you make the file password protected?

Comment: @Lasse: Visual Studio has the option of password protecting the key when you create it. I've verified that it is protected by opening the .pfx file.

Comment: What happens if you restart visual studio or windows?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I still don't get prompted for a password. I tried that before posting, but I forgot to mention it.

Comment: What happens if you delete (well, better rename :-) the SUO file? It seems to be a store for many things -- just one thing to narrow down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation for the [Create Strong Name Key Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbachc24%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> The password information is stored in your computer's cryptographic storage database.

Other information from [CLR Inside Out: Using Strong Name Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx#S8).

> You can install the private key in a key container using restrictive access control lists (ACLs) to prevent unauthorized access to the key container. Alternatively, you can store the private key on a smart card or other separate hardware device. The sn.exe tool allows you to use a different cryptographic service provider (CSP) for signing. Take a look at the –c option in the documentation for sn.exe.

Comment: Interesting... At first, I could not find any references to what this "cryptographic storage database" is. Since then I found out that I can use `sn.exe` to add and delete keys to/from the Strong Name CSP. One problem that I'm still having is that Visual Studio seems to generate a random container name for the key, so I don't know how to delete the one associated with my project. You can't use sn.exe to list all container names either.

Comment: Look into %AppData%\Microsoft\Crypto where the default CSP (cryptograhic storage provider) stores user-specific stuff, or %AllUsersProfile%\Microsoft\Crypto for machine-wide keys.

Comment: Pretty low level, but I managed to find the key (because it was the only one). I tried this tool called KeyPal, but that no longer seems to work. Thanks for the help so far though :)