# Can we assign any public key created outside the applications scope to an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a strong key using "sn -k MyStrongkey.snk" which contains a public key as well as a private key. I have extracted the public key from it using "sn -p MyStrongKey.snk MyStrongPublicKey.snk".

Now when i assign this extracted public key to a classLibrary and run the application it throws me an error - **Strong name validation failed.**

Is it not possible to create and assign a key to an assembly outside the scope of the application?

Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fully sign an assembly with a public key. This is why your are getting this error.

[You have to sign your assembly with your key pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) `MyStrongKey.snk` (containing the private key).

**Delay Sign**

**The only way to partially sign your assembly (with your public key) is through [Delay Signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye.aspx)**. But in order to use partially signed assembly **you have to configure your machine(s) to skip the signature verification**.

The following example configures the .NET Framework to skip strong name signature verification for your `ClassLibrary` assembly on your development machines:

```
sn -Vr ClassLibrary.dll
```

You can also use the sn.exe tool to skip signature verification for all assemblies signed with a particular key. For example, if you want to configure your machine to skip all assemblies delay signed with the same key as your `ClassLibrary`, you first do the following on your development machines:

```
sn -T ClassLibrary.dll
```

This prints out the value of the public key token, a shortened version of the public key that looks something like this:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility Version 2.0.50727.42
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Public key
token is b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

(Note that the actual value of the public key token will vary depending on your public key.) You then execute the following command to skip strong name verification for any assembly using that public key token:

```
sn -Vr *,b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

More info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx

**Public and Private Keys**

The public key goal is to give a public representation of your strong name signature without exposing your whole signature.

Somehow, you can see the public key as the reader key and the private key as the writer key.

Visual Studio provides a way to password protect the key pair to avoid unauthorized signature and public key extraction. But the password is stored on your computer. See [Where is the strong name key password stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177347/where-is-the-strong-name-key-password-stored)